# PHP, Mysql row data separation (,) and print <li>

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with movies. E.g:

```
table: movies
Id  -  Title  -  Actors
 2  - Avangers -  2,5,11,16

table: actors
Id  -  Name
 2  -    Jason
 5  -    Emma
 11 -    Stuart
 16 -    Thomas
```

My question: How can I print this with .li.s like this:

```
Avengers: 
*Jason
*Emma
*Stuart 
*Thomas
```

Comment: thanks for the edit, was scratching my head already trying to figure it out

Comment: That is a horrible database design. You should skip the `Actors` column on `movies`, and make a new table (e.g. `movie_actors`) to hold the n-n association (it would have two columns, `movie_id` and `actor_id`). Then what you want becomes really simple (a trivial SQL join).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must keep the actors in the movie table as a comma seperated list of Id's, then the best I can think of is: fetch that column in one query, extract the different Id's, run a query for each of the Id's to find out the name.

As one commentator said, it's not the best DB design. I would suggest removing the actor column from movie table and using a third table for movie-actor relationship :

```
table:movieactor

movie  actor
------------
2      2
2      5
2      11
2      16
```

Then you can run an inner join to find out the name of actors who appear in a given movie.

```
SELECT actors.Name from movieactor INNER JOIN actors ON movieactor.actor = actors.Id WHERE movieactor.movie = 2
```

Comment: you're welcome. Please consider giving an up-vote and/or accepting this answer if you're satisfied.